# Plot 4D data as layered heatmaps with lattice in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, plot, heatmap, lattice

How can I plot a 3D array, say `a = array(cos(1:(60*50*4)), c(60, 50, 4))`, to look something like this (preferably using `lattice` R package)?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Plot 4D data as layered heatmaps in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54072839/4194079)