# Plot 4D data as layered heatmaps in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, heatmap

I would like to create layered heatmaps using (x,y,z) coordinates and a fourth dimension, color-based, to correlate to intensity.

Each layer-related data sits in a text file with columns of x, y, z and G. The delimiter is white space. Apologies if it does not present properly.

XA
200
600
1200
1800
2400
3000
200
600
1200
1800
2400
3000

YA
0
0
0
0
0
0
600
600
600
600
600
600

ZA
600
600
600
600
600
600
600
600
600
600
600
600

GA
1.27
1.54
1.49
1.34
1.27
1.25
1.28
1.96
1.12
1.06
1.06
1.06

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data = np.load(filename)

x = np.linspace(0,2400,num=6)
y = np.linspace(0,2400,num=11)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = data[:,:,0] * 1e-3

plt.contourf(X,Y,Z)
plt.colorbar()
```

*How to read text files, create and superimpose heatmaps along the Z-axis?*

Comment: Your altitude is constant, i.e. `Z` is set to `600` for all coordinates. Is it normal ? You do not need a third dimension if so.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The z will change. I have 4 levels of data where Z = 0 then 600 then 1200 then 1800. I am sorry I did not make this clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have two txt files, namely *data-z600.txt* and *data-z1200.txt*, in the same folder as your python script, whose contents are exactly

*data-z600.txt* (yours)

```
XA YA ZA GA
200 0 600 1.27
600 0 600 1.54
1200 0 600 1.49
1800 0 600 1.34
2400 0 600 1.27
3000 0 600 1.25
200 600 600 1.28
600 600 600 1.96
1200 600 600 1.12
1800 600 600 1.06
2400 600 600 1.06
3000 600 600 1.06
```

and *data-z1200.txt* (invented on purpose)

```
XA YA ZA GA
200 0 1200 1.31
600 0 1200 2
1200 0 1200 1.63
1800 0 1200 1.36
2400 0 1200 1.31
3000 0 1200 1.35
200 600 1200 1.38
600 600 1200 1.36
1200 600 1200 1.2
1800 600 1200 1.1
2400 600 1200 1.1
3000 600 1200 1.11
```

---

Let's import all the required libraries

```
# libraries
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as si
from matplotlib import cm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

and define `grids_maker`, a function that does the job of preparing data contained in a given file, here targeted *via* the `filepath` argument.

```
def grids_maker(filepath):
    # Get the data
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=' ')

    # Make things more legible
    xy = df[['XA', 'YA']]
    x  = xy.XA
    y  = xy.YA
    z  = df.ZA
    g  = df.GA
    reso_x = reso_y = 50
    interp = 'cubic' # or 'nearest' or 'linear'

    # Convert the 4d-space's dimensions into grids
    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[
        x.min():x.max():1j*reso_x,
        y.min():y.max():1j*reso_y
    ]

    grid_z = si.griddata(
        xy, z.values,
        (grid_x, grid_y),
        method=interp
    )

    grid_g = si.griddata(
        xy, g.values,
        (grid_x, grid_y),
        method=interp
    )

    return {
        'x' : grid_x,
        'y' : grid_y,
        'z' : grid_z,
        'g' : grid_g,
    }
```

Let's use `grids_maker` over our list of files and get the extrema of each file's 4th dimension.

```
# Let's retrieve all files' contents
fgrids = dict.fromkeys([
    'data-z600.txt',
    'data-z1200.txt'
])
g_mins = []
g_maxs = []

for fpath in fgrids.keys():
    fgrids[fpath] = grids = grids_maker(fpath)
    g_mins.append(grids['g'].min())
    g_maxs.append(grids['g'].max())
```

Let's create our (all-file unifying) color-scale

```
# Create the 4th color-rendered dimension
scam = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(
    norm=cm.colors.Normalize(min(g_mins), max(g_maxs)),
    cmap='jet' # see https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html
)
```

... and finally make/show the plot

```
# Make the plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for grids in fgrids.values(): 
    scam.set_array([])   
    ax.plot_surface(
        grids['x'], grids['y'], grids['z'],
        facecolors  = scam.to_rgba(grids['g']),
        antialiased = True,
        rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=None
    )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for - thank you very much!

Comment: great job...im also looking something similar to this as it helps me to plots at every atmospheric layer..million thanks @keepAlive

Comment: Thx @Azam. I had to refactor things a little bit more in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544761/plot-4d-data-heatmap-in-python/67576211#67576211).

Comment: @keepAlive I am thinking of imposing basemap beneath the plot. I am not sure if it can happen in 3D. You have experience on this?

Comment: @Azam Indeed interesting challenge. I do have [some experience on that kind of things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088858/plotting-a-map-using-geopandas-and-matplotlib/54100726#54100726)... But I would have to try before asserting that I can "for sure".

Comment: @keepAlive please tag me in if you manage to get it solved...million thanks in advance