# Plotting a map using geopandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, geopandas

I have small csv that has 6 coordinates  from Birmingham England. I read the csv with pandas then transformed it into GeoPandas DataFrame changing my latitude and longitude columns with Shapely Points. I am now trying to plot my GeoDataframe and all I can see are the points. How do I get the Birmingham map represented as well? A good documentation source on GeoPandas would be strongly appreciated too.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('SiteLocation.csv')
df['Coordinates'] = list(zip(df.LONG, df.LAT))
df['Coordinates'] = df['Coordinates'].apply(Point)
# Building the GeoDataframe 
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='Coordinates')
geo_df.plot()
```

Comment: @Kanak can you add that as an answer?

Comment: @joris Added as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The GeoPandas documentation contains an example on how to add a background to a map (https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/plotting_basemap_background.html), which is explained in more detail below.

---

You will have to deal with [tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map), that are (png) images served through a web server, with a URL like

> `http://.../Z/X/Y.png`, where Z is the zoom level, and X and Y identify the tile

And geopandas's doc shows how to set tiles as backgrounds for your plots, fetching the correct ones and doing all the otherwise difficult job of spatial syncing, etc...

---

***Installation***

Assuming GeoPandas is already installed, you need the [`contextily`](https://github.com/darribas/contextily) package in addition. If you are under windows, you may want to pick a look at [How to install Contextily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149384/how-to-install-contextily)

***Use case***

Create a python script and  define the *[contextily helper function](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/plotting_basemap_background.html#contextily-helper-function)*

```
import contextily as ctx

def add_basemap(ax, zoom, url='http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/tileZ/tileX/tileY.png'):
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = ax.axis()
    basemap, extent = ctx.bounds2img(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, zoom=zoom, url=url)
    ax.imshow(basemap, extent=extent, interpolation='bilinear')
    # restore original x/y limits
    ax.axis((xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))
```

and play

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

# Let's define our raw data, whose epsg is 4326
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'LAT'  :[-22.266415, -20.684157],
    'LONG' :[166.452764, 164.956089],
})
df['coords'] = list(zip(df.LONG, df.LAT))

# ... turn them into geodataframe, and convert our
# epsg into 3857, since web map tiles are typically
# provided as such.
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, crs  ={'init': 'epsg:4326'},
    geometry = df['coords'].apply(Point)
).to_crs(epsg=3857)

# ... and make the plot
ax = geo_df.plot(
    figsize= (5, 5),
    alpha  = 1
)
add_basemap(ax, zoom=10)
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.title('Kaledonia : From Hienghène to Nouméa')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

*Note: you can play with the `zoom` to find the good resolution for the map.* E.g./I.e. :

[image]

*... and such resolutions implicitly call for changing the x/y limits.*

Comment: Any question @Herc01 ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean with the last remark about the zoom level? Normally you should not need to edit the x/y limits manually if changing the zoom level.

Comment: @joris, what I meant is that using the value set for the parameter `zoom` is somehow equivalent to changing the (image) resolution of the map. Do you agree with that?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the "zoom" means. It might be a bit confusing name as the map itself is not zoomed in (looking at smaller area), but a lower/higher `zoom` zooms in for the full area and thus resulting in a lower/higher resolution.

Comment: @joris Are you on Windows ? it looks like you ignore how difficult it is to install contextily under it. This diffculty is a no go for most of windows-users. Hence the section that was explaining how to (finally be able to successfully) install contextily. Doing `pip3 install contextily` under windows just don't work.

Comment: sorry, I was planning to add a comment in the edit why I removed it, but forgot that: I know it can certainly be hard to install, but I think here it distracts from the actual answer (and it was also not the only possible way to install, eg for someone using conda that would have been the wrong way). Would you like to make a new question "How to install contextily?", and add your answer on that part there. And then we can link to that question from here (and keep this answer focused on the how).

Comment: @Kanak; yes  I have a question  about the epsg; where do I have find. I found a map and would like to do the same and what do you mean by  convert since our epsg is 3857.?

Comment: @Herc01 There is the epsg of your points, and that of the map onto which you want to project your points, and the two must be the same. I do not know how familiar your are with geographic stuffs, but it is as if you had a x/y plan whose units were expressed in *cm* on the one hand, and some points whose coordinates were in *inch* on the other hand. The epsg of the map that is used in the example is 3857. In case you want to use the same map, you just have to figure out what the epsg of your points is. There is no systematic way to do so AFAIK. Do you have some pairs of lat-long to show me?

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add the use case concerning zooming whereby the basemap is updated according to the new `xlim` and `ylim` coordinates. A solution I have come up with is:

- First set callbacks on the `ax` that can detect `xlim_changed` and `ylim_changed`
- Once both have been detected as changed get the new `plot_area` calling `ax.get_xlim()` and `ax.get_ylim()`
- Then clear the `ax` and re-plot the basemap and any other data

Example for a world map showing the capitals. You notice when you zoom in the resolution of the map is being updated.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import contextily as ctx


figsize = (12, 10)
osm_url = 'http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
EPSG_OSM = 3857
EPSG_WGS84 = 4326

class MapTools:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cities = gpd.read_file(
            gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
        self.cities.crs = EPSG_WGS84
        self.cities = self.convert_to_osm(self.cities)

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=figsize)
        self.callbacks_connect()

        # get extent of the map for all cities
        self.cities.plot(ax=self.ax)
        self.plot_area = self.ax.axis()

    def convert_to_osm(self, df):
        return df.to_crs(epsg=EPSG_OSM)

    def callbacks_connect(self):
        self.zoomcallx = self.ax.callbacks.connect(
            'xlim_changed', self.on_limx_change)
        self.zoomcally = self.ax.callbacks.connect(
            'ylim_changed', self.on_limy_change)

        self.x_called = False
        self.y_called = False

    def callbacks_disconnect(self):
        self.ax.callbacks.disconnect(self.zoomcallx)
        self.ax.callbacks.disconnect(self.zoomcally)

    def on_limx_change(self, _):
        self.x_called = True
        if self.y_called:
            self.on_lim_change()

    def on_limy_change(self, _):
        self.y_called = True
        if self.x_called:
            self.on_lim_change()

    def on_lim_change(self):
        xlim = self.ax.get_xlim()
        ylim = self.ax.get_ylim()
        self.plot_area = (*xlim, *ylim)
        self.blit_map()

    def add_base_map_osm(self):
        if abs(self.plot_area[1] - self.plot_area[0]) < 100:
            zoom = 13

        else:
            zoom = 'auto'

        try:
            basemap, extent = ctx.bounds2img(
                self.plot_area[0], self.plot_area[2],
                self.plot_area[1], self.plot_area[3],
                zoom=zoom,
                url=osm_url,)
            self.ax.imshow(basemap, extent=extent, interpolation='bilinear')

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'unable to load map: {e}')

    def blit_map(self):
        self.ax.cla()
        self.callbacks_disconnect()
        cities = self.cities.cx[
            self.plot_area[0]:self.plot_area[1],
            self.plot_area[2]:self.plot_area[3]]
        cities.plot(ax=self.ax, color='red', markersize=3)

        print('*'*80)
        print(self.plot_area)
        print(f'{len(cities)} cities in plot area')

        self.add_base_map_osm()
        self.callbacks_connect()

    @staticmethod
    def show():
        plt.show()


def main():
    map_tools = MapTools()
    map_tools.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Runs on Linux Python3.8 with following pip installs

```
affine==2.3.0
attrs==19.3.0
autopep8==1.4.4
Cartopy==0.17.0
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
cligj==0.5.0
contextily==1.0rc2
cycler==0.10.0
descartes==1.1.0
Fiona==1.8.11
geographiclib==1.50
geopandas==0.6.2
geopy==1.20.0
idna==2.8
joblib==0.14.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.1.2
mercantile==1.1.2
more-itertools==8.0.0
munch==2.5.0
numpy==1.17.4
packaging==19.2
pandas==0.25.3
Pillow==6.2.1
pluggy==0.13.1
py==1.8.0
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pyparsing==2.4.5
pyproj==2.4.1
pyshp==2.1.0
pytest==5.3.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
rasterio==1.1.1
requests==2.22.0
Rtree==0.9.1
Shapely==1.6.4.post2
six==1.13.0
snuggs==1.4.7
urllib3==1.25.7
wcwidth==0.1.7
```

Note especially requirement for `contextily==1.0rc2`

On windows I use Conda (P3.7.3) and don't forget to set the User variables:

`GDAL c:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\<your environment>\Library\share\gdal`

`PROJLIB c:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\<your environment>\Library\share`

Answer (score 0):

Try [df.unary_union](http://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html#GeoSeries.unary_union). The function will aggregate points into a single geometry. 
Jupyter Notebook [can plot it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skU96.png)

Comment: Sorry mate -- that was not what I was looking for. But thanks . You look at some  other open questions