# How to install Contextily?

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas, contextily

This question is written in relation with the answer to [Plotting a map using geopandas and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54100726/4194079).

The main point is that installing (spatial) libraries such as [Proj.4](https://proj4.org/) or [Contextily](https://github.com/darribas/contextily) can be a confusing task under Windows, so that most of the time we are advised to directly

> use the [OSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) software distribution.

An example of such an advise [here](https://proj4.org/install.html#windows).

*A contrario*, the task is rather easy with other operating systems.

---

*The main idea is to provide interrogative users with a "lite" installation approach.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Using Anaconda / conda**

If you are using the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/download) or in general the conda package manager (which I recommend for installing the python geo stack), it should suffice to install contextily with:

```
conda install contextily --channel conda-forge
```

This will automatically install all python and C dependencies (proj.4, GDAL, ...)

This should work on all platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac).

Answer (score 6):

***Windows***

*(Without any conda-like distribution)*

After manually downloading the WHL files from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Open an *Administrator* Command Prompt and type (illustrated on Python3.6 32bit):

```
pip3.6 install GDAL-2.3.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl && setx GDAL_VERSION "2.3.3"
pip3.6 install Fiona-1.8.4-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
pip3.6 install geopandas-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
pip3.6 install proj
pip3.6 install Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
pip3.6 install Cartopy-0.17.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
pip3.6 install rasterio-1.0.13-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
pip3.6 install contextily
```

*(tested)*.

Comment: I would be glad to know the reason behind the downvote. Indeed, 1) the answer above works and 2) we may not want to use conda for many reasons, which I discourage incidentally.

Answer (score 1):

Well from oficial install page with conda is :

```
conda install -c conda-forge contextily
```

[Install geopandas and contextily](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/course-info/Installing_Anacondas_GIS.html?highlight=contextily)