# Stack of heatmaps seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I'd like to make a graph that looks similar to this.

[image]

The [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) make it clear how to make the 2d version but I'm struggling to figure out how to make this type of graph.

Comment: A start: [plot-4d-data-as-layered-heatmaps-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072839/plot-4d-data-as-layered-heatmaps-in-python)

Comment: @JohanC Looks laborious. There hasts to be a better way.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582105/python-plot-stacked-image-slices) is another approach.