# Plot 4D data heatmap in Python

Tags: python, 3d, 2d, heatmap

hey how can I plot a 2D heatmap in 3D? Now I create a python script to make a 2D Heatmap Plot with data from CSV (CSV format: x,y,z,v).
For example:

First csv

```
0,000;-110,000;110,000;0,101
```

Second csv

```
0,000;-66,000;110,000;0,104
```

Third csv

```
0,000;-22,000;110,000;0,119
```

....

In this example, it is a heatmap in xz-plane and I create e.g. five more plots, so that I can insert six xz-plane Plots in a 3D room.
In [4D heatmap plot with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072839/plot-4d-data-as-layered-heatmaps-in-python) there is a very nice example for doing it. But I don't know how to use it in my case.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


'Create a list for every parameter'
x = []
y = []
z = []
v = []

file_path = "path/."

'Insert data from csv into lists'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path, topdown=False):
   for name in files:
       if name[-4:] != '.csv': continue
       with open(os.path.join(root, name)) as data:
          data = np.genfromtxt((line.replace(',', '.') for line in data), delimiter=";")
          if data[1] == 22: 
            x.append(data[0])
            y.append(data[1])
            z.append(data[2])
            v.append(data[3])

'Create axis data'
xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 1000)
zi = np.linspace(min(z), max(z), 1000)
vi = griddata((x, z), v, (xi[None,:], zi[:,None]), method='cubic')

'Create the contour plot'
CS = plt.contourf(xi, zi, vi, 20, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow)
plt.title("Heatmap xz-plane", y=1.05, 
          fontweight="bold")
plt.xlabel("length x in cm")
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 201, step=40))
plt.ylabel("height z in cm")
plt.yticks(np.arange(110, 251, step=20))
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label("velocity v in m/s", labelpad=10)
plt.savefig('testplot.png', dpi=400)  
plt.show()
```

---

<sub>*Satisfying the request of @keepAlive wishing to see the result of his untested answer... :*</sub>

it actually works great :-)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are all your datafiles identically structured  ? I think that showing us how your data look like may help us figuring out what you want to achieve. Otherwise, it is hard to tell what you have exactly in mind when doing, e.g. `data[1] == 22`.... There is likely a better approach on that matter as well.

Comment: Yes, all csv files are structured as: `x;y;z;v`. But only one data per parameter (one row). Every csv file has the following input e.g. `50,0;80,0;120,0;1,536`. The if statement with `if data[1] == 22` is a example, because the original code is much longer but is for the function not interested

Comment: Ok. I have updated my question and insert the data of three csv files. Or do you need more?

Comment: hey @nico.wagner I am really curious about why your account has been deleted. May be one day you will see this comment, and answer me back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of the [cited example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54075350/4194079), so I think that copying/pasting myself is not really a problem.</sub>

*Note that your dataset does not look (at least) 3-dimensional. But I will assume there is an unwilling selection bias.*

You first need to aggregate your "points" per level of altitude, which I assume is the third component of your vectors. They will be constitutive of your planes once gathered.

```
# libraries
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as si
from matplotlib import cm
import collections as co  # <------------------
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

planes = co.defaultdict(list)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path, topdown=False):
   # [...]
       # [...]
       # [...]
          # [...]
          # [...]
            level = data[2]  # <------ third component.
            planes[level].append(data)
```

Now, at that stage, we have a list of arrays per `level`. Let's define our `grids_maker` function

```
def grids_maker(arrays_list, colnames=list('xyzg')):
    # 0- The idea behind `list('xyzg')` is only to change the order
    #    of names, not the names as such. In case for example you
    #    want to use another component than the third to organize
    #    your planes.
    # 1- Instantiate a dataframe so as to minimize the modification
    #    of the function copied/pasted pasted from
    #    https://stackoverflow.com/a/54075350/4194079
    # 2- Pandas is also going to do some other jobs for us, such as
    #    stacking arrays, etc....
    df = pd.DataFrame(arrays_list, columns=colnames)

    # Make things more legible
    xy = df.loc[:, ['x', 'y']]
    x  = xy.x
    y  = xy.y
    z  = df.z
    g  = df.g
    reso_x = reso_y = 50
    interp = 'cubic' # or 'nearest' or 'linear'

    # Convert the 4d-space's dimensions into grids
    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[
        x.min():x.max():1j*reso_x,
        y.min():y.max():1j*reso_y
    ]

    grid_z = si.griddata(
        xy, z.values,
        (grid_x, grid_y),
        method=interp
    )

    grid_g = si.griddata(
        xy, g.values,
        (grid_x, grid_y),
        method=interp
    )

    return {
        'x' : grid_x,
        'y' : grid_y,
        'z' : grid_z,
        'g' : grid_g,
    }
```

Let's use `grids_maker` over our list of arrays and get the extrema of each z-level's 4th dimension.

```
g_mins = []
g_maxs = []
lgrids = {}

for level, arrays_list in planes.items():
    lgrids[level] = grids = grids_maker(arrays_list)
    g_mins.append(grids['g'].min())
    g_maxs.append(grids['g'].max())
```

Let's create our (all-file unifying) color-scale and show the plot.

```
# Create the 4th color-rendered dimension
scam = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(
    norm=cm.colors.Normalize(min(g_mins), max(g_maxs)),
    cmap='jet' # see https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html
)
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for grids in lgrids.values(): 
    scam.set_array([])   
    ax.plot_surface(
        grids['x'], grids['y'], grids['z'],
        facecolors  = scam.to_rgba(grids['g']),
        antialiased = True,
        rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=None
    )
plt.show()
```

I would be glad to see the result.

Comment: Any question @nico ?

Comment: No. It works great. See this two pictures in my edited question. Thank you!

Comment: Thx for your pictures @nico (!) Always nice to see that !

Comment: Hey keepAlive (I could not tag you), I have tested your code and everything looks good. However, I noticed that the heatmap colors are a bit darker then the colorbar somehow? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @mdpoleto Nop. How do you set it ? Do you provide it with `scam` ? I mean, doing [`plt.colorbar(mappable=scam)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) ?

Comment: Yes, but I realized the problem was the use of shade=True within plot_surface(). Once I set shade=False, the colors a back in their original brightness and they match the colorbar again. Thanks!

Comment: Actually @keepAlive, for the sake of discussing the intellectual debate of whether plagiarizing yourself is an issue: even though you are the author, you should probably not just copy paste but instead reference to the original post :)

Comment: Do not hesitate to have a look at the other answer @Ma, you'll see that the above answer is far from being 100% copied/pasted. Modifications/adaptations are generous. That being said, isn't the heading disclaimer exactly referring to it?