# Can we put a flat heatmap on a 3D axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap

Can we plot a straight heatmap on a 3D axis? The heatmap is as follows:
I am able to get a 3D elevation map, but I am not looking for that. I just want this straight lying on a 3D axis.

Code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import interpolate

excel_data_df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

X= excel_data_df['x'].tolist()
Y= excel_data_df['y'].tolist()
Z= excel_data_df['z'].tolist()

X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
Z = np.array(Z)
# Flatten trial dataset to meet your requirement:
x = X.ravel()
y = Y.ravel()
z = Z.ravel()

# Resampling on as square grid with given resolution:
resolution = 8
xlin = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), resolution)
ylin = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), resolution)
Xlin, Ylin = np.meshgrid(xlin, ylin)

# Linear multi-dimensional interpolation:
interpolant = interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator([r for r in zip(x, y)], z)
Zhat = interpolant(Xlin.ravel(), Ylin.ravel()).reshape(Xlin.shape)
cmap = 'jet'

# Render and interpolate again if necessary:
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.imshow(Zhat, origin="lower", cmap=cmap, interpolation='bicubic',extent=[min(x),max(x),min(y),max(y)])

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+1, 1.0))

axe.grid(True, linewidth=0.3, color='w')
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = min(z), vmax = max(z), clip = False)

plt.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap = cmap, norm=norm))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I dont know how you want to look at a 3d graph, its physically impossible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072839/plot-4d-data-as-layered-heatmaps-in-python . Like this except that I want one.

Comment: Ahhhhh now i got it

Comment: But now i dont get what the problem is, you have a 2d plane and the color for your "third" dimension, but its actually not 3d but fractal, so 2.5d or something, is that the problem?

Comment: I just want it to look like the link I shared